# Strange triple integral of an inverse function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let
$$
\Omega(a, b, c) = \min\left\{\theta\ge0\ \text{s.t.}\ \tan(a\theta) + \tan(b\theta) + \tan(c\theta) = 1\right\}
$$

What is the value of the following integral

> $$
> I = \iiint_{[1,\infty)^3}\Omega(a, b, c)\frac{\text{d}c}{c}\frac{\text{d}b}{b}\frac{\text{d}a}{a}?
> $$

My friend tells there's a closed form for it, but I think he's pulling my leg. Any ideas? Does it even exist?

Comment: Is $\Omega$ simplified if $a < b < c$?

Comment: @Real what do you mean by "simplified"? I'm not entirely on board.

Comment: How is $\Omega(a,b,c)$ defined if there is no $\theta \in [0,\pi)$ such that $\tan(a\theta)+\tan(b\theta)+\tan(c\theta) = 1$? This can happen if $a,b,c$ are small.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing that out, I thought something was wrong with the definition of $\Omega$. It should just be the minimum positive $\theta$ over the entire positive half real line.

Comment: For any $0 \le a,b,c \le 1$, we have $\Omega(a,b,c) \ge \arctan\frac{1}{3}$. Hence, $I = \displaystyle\iiint_{[0,1]^3}\Omega(a,b,c)\dfrac{dc}{c}\dfrac{db}{b}\dfrac{da}{a} \ge \iiint_{[0,1]^3}\arctan\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{dc}{c}\dfrac{db}{b}\dfrac{da}{a}$, which I believe diverges. Are you sure the integral is correct?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Ha! Hell if I knew whether it was correct or not. My friend gave it to me, told me there was a closed form, and left. Knew he was probably kidding. However, I still am interested in integrals of this form. Can we consider the integral over $[1, \infty)^3$ instead?